# JQuery дочерние элементы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем привет, есть такой список, мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на определенный элемент, он открывал дочерний подпункт а не все сразу.

```js
 $(function () {
  $('.podpunkt').hide();
  $('.punkt').click(function () {
   $('.punkt > .podpunkt').show();
   
  });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li class="punkt">P1
    <ul class="podpunkt">PP1
     <li>TEXT1</li>
     <li>TEXT2</li>
     <li>TEXT3</li>
     <li>TEXT4</li>
     <li>TEXT5</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="punkt">P2
    <ul class="podpunkt">PP2
     <li>TEXT1</li>
     <li>TEXT2</li>
     <li>TEXT3</li>
     <li>TEXT4</li>
     <li>TEXT5</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="punkt">P3
    <ul class="podpunkt">PP3
     <li>TEXT1</li>
     <li>TEXT2</li>
     <li>TEXT3</li>
     <li>TEXT4</li>
     <li>TEXT5</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="punkt">P4
    <ul class="podpunkt">PP4
     <li>TEXT1</li>
     <li>TEXT2</li>
     <li>TEXT3</li>
     <li>TEXT4</li>
     <li>TEXT5</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="punkt">P5
    <ul class="podpunkt">PP5
     <li>TEXT1</li>
     <li>TEXT2</li>
     <li>TEXT3</li>
     <li>TEXT4</li>
     <li>TEXT5</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Иcпользуйте `(event.target || event.srcElement).firstChild` для получения дочернего списка - но это на чистом JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замени

```
$('.punkt > .podpunkt').show();
```

на

```
$(this).find('.podpunkt').show();
```

или на

```
$('.podpunkt', this).show();
```

без разницы

---

Ведь ты сам говоришь, что при клике на пункт, открывались все дочерние.. А при `this` ты уже указываешь к чему этот подпункт относится, к какому контексту

```js
$(function () {            
    $('.punkt').click(function () { // $('.punkt').on('click', function () {
        $('.podpunkt').hide();
     $(this).find('.podpunkt').show(); // $('.podpunkt', this).show();          
    });
});
```

```css
.podpunkt {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="punkt">P1
     <ul class="podpunkt">PP1
      <li>TEXT1</li>
      <li>TEXT2</li>
      <li>TEXT3</li>
      <li>TEXT4</li>
      <li>TEXT5</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="punkt">P2
     <ul class="podpunkt">PP2
      <li>TEXT1</li>
      <li>TEXT2</li>
      <li>TEXT3</li>
      <li>TEXT4</li>
      <li>TEXT5</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="punkt">P3
     <ul class="podpunkt">PP3
      <li>TEXT1</li>
      <li>TEXT2</li>
      <li>TEXT3</li>
      <li>TEXT4</li>
      <li>TEXT5</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="punkt">P4
     <ul class="podpunkt">PP4
      <li>TEXT1</li>
      <li>TEXT2</li>
      <li>TEXT3</li>
      <li>TEXT4</li>
      <li>TEXT5</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="punkt">P5
     <ul class="podpunkt">PP5
      <li>TEXT1</li>
      <li>TEXT2</li>
      <li>TEXT3</li>
      <li>TEXT4</li>
      <li>TEXT5</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```